# jQuery Tools Scrollable - only scrolls to 10 thumbnails

Tags: jquery, carousel, jquery-tools, thumbnails, scrollable

I have [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html) set up so that the thumbnails are acting as navigation. This works great with galleries that only have 10 images like this example:

http://www.toneblu.com/ashleighjuarez/musicandevents.html

But my client has galleries that will have 15, 20, or 25 images in them. The "Lifestyle" gallery has 20 images but only scrolls to #10 and then it stops. When I set `overflow: visible;`, all images are in line and can be clicked. But the scroller doesn't work.

Can someone please help? I've spent hours experimenting but cannot get it to work. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You will never get it to work quite right and the more galleries you have, the more HTML/CSS you will have to write.  It's ridiculous.  I abandoned it long ago when I had issues with two very simple scrollers.  jQuery's tagline is _"write less, do more"_.  jQuery Tools has succeeded in making it _"do less, write a butt-load of code by hand"_.  There are dozens of great jQuery scroller plugins out there... Nivo Slider, Orbit, jCarousel, etc., not to mention that the last stable release of jQuery Tools was over a year ago and only officially supports IE versions less than 9 and jQuery 1.4.2.

Comment: More FYI:  [jQuery Tools vs. jQueryUI](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-tools-vs-jquery-ui).  Obviously, you do not have to use jQueryUI either but the points made in the article are valid nonetheless.

Comment: Well can't say that is what I wanted to hear. Ha.

My client wants a very clean slider with scrolling thumbnails that have overflow hidden. I researched several of the ones you mentioned before trying Scrollable. Originally she wanted http://simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/, but I talked her out of flash. I hate to abandon Scrollable already...hopefully someone can help me out.

Thank you for the input and information though.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news but everything indicates it's a dead-end project.  This brings up a new point you should be aware of.  You're struggling to get your code working with the existing version.  However, it's not officially compatible with anything past jQuery 1.4.2 including IE 9.  Tero, the author of jQuery Tools has publicly stated in his forum that any new version of jQuery Tools will render your code obsolete.  In other words, you're doing all this work for nothing as it will have to be rewritten for any newer version of jQuery Tools... if it's ever released.

Comment: Dang, I've spent no less that 8 hours setting this up and troubleshooting. Thanks for the input. I'll try implementing the Nivo Slider with thumbnails.

Comment: Nivo is top-notch software.  Don't feel so bad... I spent two full days simply trying to get two jQuery Tools Scrollables working on the same page.  It's eventually possible, but instead I setup jCarousel... only took 20 minutes.